Saving Date / DateTime type values in Data Tables
i had been trying to insert data from an excel file into a Db Data table .
i had so much trouble with specifically inserting the Date or Datetime values into the database table columns .
I posted this question before about the same subject : Converting from string to type date is not valid .
And it seems like the problem actually originated in the process of inserting the Data from the excel file into the Data table ( it was inserted as string ) - as a user suggested in the previous question , Not in while inserting into the SQL Server .
This is the part of code where i inserted the data into the data table :
Dim wb1 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook("C:\Users\oxy\Downloads\Test\Test2.xlsx")
Dim ws As IXLWorksheet = wb1.Worksheet(1)



Dim wb2 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(TextBox1.Text)
Dim ws2 As IXLWorksheet = wb2.Worksheet(1)
ws2.Range("A:G").CopyTo(ws.Cell("A1"))


Dim wb3 As IXLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(TextBox2.Text)
Dim ws3 As IXLWorksheet = wb3.Worksheet(1)
ws3.Range("A:N").CopyTo(ws.Cell("F1"))

Dim dt1 As New DataTable
Dim dt2 As New DataTable

Dim firstrow As Boolean = True 
For Each row As IXLRow In ws2.Rows.Skip(0)

    If firstrow Then
        For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells
            dt1.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString)
        Next
        firstrow = False
        dt1.Columns("Date").DataType = GetType(Date)
        dt1.Columns("First Check In").DataType = GetType(Date)
        dt1.Columns("Last Check Out").DataType = GetType(Date)

    End If
    Exit For
Next



For Each row As IXLRow In ws2.Rows.Skip(2)
    dt1.Rows.Add()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
        dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value
        i += 1
    Next
Next

I added this part recently :
    dt1.Columns("Date").DataType = GetType(Date)
    dt1.Columns("First Check In").DataType = GetType(Date)
    dt1.Columns("Last Check Out").DataType = GetType(Date) 

This is how the excel data i'm trying to pass looks like :



Employee   ID
Date
Weekday
First Check In
Last Check Out




10
2024-04-15
Monday

15:04


10
2024-04-16
Tuesday
08:46
14:41


10
2024-04-17
Wednesday
08:34



10
2024-04-18
Thursday
07:50
15:18



So now while debugging i got the following error :

'Unable to cast object of type 'ClosedXML.Excel.XLCellValue' to type
'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <2024-04-16> in Date Column.
Expected type is DateTime.'

The error ocurres on this line of code :
dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value


I made sure the column is set to Date type in the excel file
I tried to change the Datatype of the column " Date" to " DateTime " instead of Date ( even though it doesn't make sense ) . and i got the exact same error .


If cell.Value gives you an object of type ClosedXML.Excel.XLCellValue then you need to look at that type and see what members it has to get the actual data out. That data may or may not already be a DateTime value. If it is then you can use it directly, perhaps after casting. If it's not then you may have to geta String and convert that to a DateTime.

I just took 30 seconds to do a web search for that type, which took me to the relevant documentation, which shows that there is such a method: https://docs.closedxml.io/en/latest/api/index.html#function-ClosedXML.Excel.XLCellValue.GetDateTime

There's also a property to check whether it is a DateTime first: https://docs.closedxml.io/en/latest/api/index.html#var-ClosedXML.Excel.XLCellValue.IsDateTime.

It looks to me like you should be storing the check in and out times in the database as times, in which case you should be storing then in the DataTable as TimeSpan. If I remember correctly, you're using SQL Server as your database, which has data types dedicated to just dates and just times.

@jmcilhinney checking this documentation i pretty much managed to get the data into the dt using "Cell.Value.GetDataTime" / GetTimeSpan .. etc ,i'm not sure if it's actually successfully inserted yet since i'm having a problem inserting the Null Data into the dt since Date / TimeSpan / DateTime type columns do not allow Nulls .

tried using DateTime? , Date? , TimeSpan? as well , it returns an error
'DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.'

ADO.NET uses DBNull.Value to represent nulls, because it predates nullable types. I suspect you'd use the IsBlank property to check whether you should assign null to the table field.

i don't really understand how can i use DBNull.Value in this case x) , and yes i did use 'IsBlank'  & cell.Value.GetBlank to try to insert the Null values into the columns when this error was generated .

Have you tried dt1.Columns("Date").DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"); and of course applying the same idea to the other columns?

I suggest that you combine the dates and times from the spreadsheet(s) into datetimes. It will be easier to work with. Also, you can check if the datetime is valid and if not then set the .Value of the relevant parameter to DbNull.Value. There is no need to use a DataTable to transfer the data from the spreadsheet to the database, it's just an extra complication.

@LajosArpad this returns an error (( " System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Data.DataColumnCollection.this[string].get returned Nothing.)) on line ((dt1.Columns("FirstCheckIn").DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.TimeSpan")))

@AndrewMorton i will try so , but how is that an extra ? , i tried doing this without using a db at the beggening and it was so painful to do so . see this

@AndrewMorton and yup , combining Dates and times in the spreadsheet pretty much solves the null values problem . ty

@jmcilhinney could you please check this out Link

Something I'm really not a fan of is people providing a link to some pages with no information about why I would want to. If it's too much trouble for you to provide a few words of explanation...

im sorry , it is just a link for a user's comment that basically adjusted a code that you wrote for me earlier , you mentioned to me before that i should not loop into the table one row after another when i insert it into SQL  instead insert it " in one go" , so i just asked him if that was possible to do that without using hard-coded variables / AND without looping . and mentioned your earlier comment for him "(

Sorry, I've meant dt1.Columns("First Check In")
